# PowerBiEmbedded token using Service Principal

Tags: powerbi-embedded, azure-service-principal

I have a C# App that uses a Active Directory User to perform the following operations, I am trying to convert it to use a Active Directory Service Principal. I am using **Power Embedded Workspace with Premium Capacity in Azure**

- Create DataSet
- Create Report
- Refresh DataSet

However I am running into issues when trying to get the same actions performed using a **Service Principal**.

## What have I tried

I have the following things setup

### 01. Tenant Settings -> Developer Options :

- created app registration in Azure Active Directory
- created security group in Azure Active Directory.
- added Service Principal (created in step 1) to the security group (created in step 2)
- As app.powerbi.com administrator enabled the developer settings -> access to admin api
- restricted the access to a specific group and made sure that the Service Principal I am using is added to this security group
  [image]

### 02. Workspace Settings : powerbi workspace -> access control

- added Service Principal as "Admin" to the workspace

### 03. App Owns Data workflow

- used the suggested github repository [App Owns Data Solution](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/.NET%20Core/Embed%20for%20your%20customers/AppOwnsData)
- plugged in the correct values in `appsettings.json`

  - ClientID,
  - SecretKey
  - TenantID
  - WorkspaceId
  - ReportId

I am getting the error

```
Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperations.GetReportInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync(Guid groupId, Guid reportId, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.GetReportInGroupAsync(IReportsOperations operations, Guid groupId, Guid reportId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.GetReportInGroup(IReportsOperations operations, Guid groupId, Guid reportId)
at AppOwnsData.Services.PbiEmbedService.GetEmbedParams(Guid workspaceId, Guid reportId, Guid additionalDatasetId) in C:\Campuslabs\TeamFoundation\PowerBI-Developer-Samples\.NET Core\Embed for your customers\AppOwnsData\Services\PbiEmbedService.cs:line 46
at AppOwnsData.Controllers.EmbedInfoController.GetEmbedInfo() in C:\Campuslabs\TeamFoundation\PowerBI-Developer-Samples\.NET Core\Embed for your customers\AppOwnsData\Controllers\EmbedInfoController.cs:line 45
```

My question is

1. How do I troubleshoot this issue
2. Are Service Principal Credentials allowed to refresh / create / data sets on Power Embedded Workspace with Premium Capacity

Comment: To refresh a dataset, you must be the owner of the dataset. This means that the dataset must be created by the service principal, or you must change the owner to be the service principal (see [Take Over In Group API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/take-over-in-group) ).

Answer (score 1):

1. Regarding trouble shooting, it seems from the error stack you sent that the issue lies with permissions on the workspace, double check that the Service Principal you added as an admin on the workspace is the same one you are using in your app.
2. Regarding the second question, the answer to that is yes. A Service Principal can refresh / create / data sets on Power Embedded Workspace with Premium Capacity.